# tab sequence of DM script UI

Tags: dm-script

I built a UI in DM. The "Tab" key can go through the fields in sequence. The tab sequence is reversed when the same program runs in GMS 1.x and GMS 3.x. Example code is like this,

```
Class UI:uiframe {
    TagGroup MainFrame(object self) {
        TagGroup Dialog=DLGCreateDialog("")
        
        tagGroup lbl1=DLGCreateLabel("label 1:") 
        tagGroup fld1=DLGCreateStringField("string 1",20).DLGIdentifier("field1")
        tagGroup grp1=DLGGroupItems(lbl1,fld1).DLGTableLayout(2,1,0)
        
        tagGroup lbl2=DLGCreateLabel("label 2:") 
        tagGroup fld2=DLGCreateStringField("string 2",20).DLGIdentifier("field2")
        tagGroup grp2=DLGGroupItems(lbl2,fld2).DLGTableLayout(2,1,0)
        
        tagGroup lbl3=DLGCreateLabel("label 3:") 
        tagGroup fld3=DLGCreateStringField("string 3",20).DLGIdentifier("field3")
        tagGroup grp3=DLGGroupItems(lbl3,fld3).DLGTableLayout(2,1,0)
        
        Dialog.DLGAddElement(grp1)
        Dialog.DLGAddElement(grp2)
        Dialog.DLGAddElement(grp3)
        return Dialog
    }

    UI(object self) { //constructor, start from here
        self.init(self.MainFrame())
        self.display(" ").WindowSetFramePosition(800, 30 )
    }
    ~UI(object self) {
        result("\nUI destructed")
    }
}
void main() {
    object My_UI = Alloc(UI)
    Return
}
{
    main()
}
```

In GMS 1.x, the tab sequence is the same order the field is put into the dialog. That is, if the focus is at fld1, tab key will move the focus to fld2, then fld 3. But in GMS 3.x, it is in the reverse order. Can I control this with code so that the UI behaves the same when using Tab Key?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not.
All of "dialog" building in GMS really is just putting together a taggroup.

You can just use `dialog.TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow("",0)` to see this.

The application interprets the tagGroup and builds a proper dialog out of it, so the 'action' is in this transformation and outside script-control. There is no property that can be added to influence this.

Maybe file a bug-report/feature request at Gatan.com ? It sounds like an unintentional change...

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can we catch that "Dialog" and reverse the order after the components are displayed? The constructor calls "self.init(self.MainFrame())", can we catch the returned taggroup by MainFrame? - Want to see if we can modify it after the display.

Comment: As suggested by the answer, the layout of dialogs cannot generally be changed once the TagGroup descriptor has been submitted to the UIFrame Init method. There are a few ways to dynamically alter and update the dialog view at runtime (for example through use of layered panels) but these would not affect the tab sequence when navigating via keyboard.